# Why is List compatible with List<?> but List<List> is not with List<List<?>>?

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I was implementing some interfaces with non generic code, and I wanted to get rid of the warnings without `@SupressWarnings`. But then I ended up in a situation like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    public abstract List m1();

    public abstract List<List> m2();

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public List<?> m1() { // the compiler is happy with this
        // whatever
    }

    @Override
    public List<List<?>> m2() { // but not with this
        // whatever
    }

}
```

Why? Why can I change the return type from `List` to `List<?>` when overriding a method and can't apply the same logic with `List<List>` to `List<List<?>>`?

This is the message the compiler gives me:

> return type `java.util.List<java.util.List<?>>` is not compatible with `java.util.List<java.util.List>`

But why is `List` compatible with `List<?>` and `List<List>` is not with `List<List<?>>`?

I made a couple of demos:

- [changing just the first method](https://ideone.com/1kDT21)
- [changing both](https://ideone.com/DF43JK) (does not compile)

Comment: It is _generally_ the case with generics that if `B` is a subtype of `A` that you cannot assign `List<B>` to `List<A>`.

Comment: Right, I'm kind of surprised that `List<?>` is compatible with `List`.  Maybe a special case they allowed to make "upgrading" code easier.

Comment: Dang, it's a duplicate of a duplicate, haha. It's kinda hard to find these questions with the `<` and `> ` symbols.

Comment: `List` is compatible with `List<List<?>>` :)